# How to redirect from appspot domain to custom domain?

Tags: google-app-engine, web2py

I found this post from Amir in regards to redirecting request from google.appspot domain to the custom domain.    My question is where do you put something like this using Web2py?

```
**To just add a custom domain, just follow the instructions here: http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/domains.html
And once that works, you can put a check in your code to forward anyone landing on the appspot.com domain to your domain: (example in python)
def get(self):
  if self.request.host.endswith('appspot.com'):
    return self.redirect('www.jaavuu.com', True)
  # ... your code ...**
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the beginning of your first model file, you can do:

```
if request.env.http_host.endswith('appspot.com'):
    redirect(URL(host='www.yourdomain.com', args=request.args, vars=request.vars))
```

This will preserve the entire original URL, except for replacing yourdomain.appspot.com with www.yourdomain.com. Note, `URL()` will automatically fill in the current controller and function, but you have to explicitly pass the current request.args and request.vars to make sure they get preserved.

Comment: As noted in the answer, at the beginning of the first model file (model files are executed in alphabetical order) -- that way, it will redirect before any other app code gets run.

Comment: @Anthony: Thanks But from where "request" param would come? Could you please elaborate? (As i'm not using Web2Py..) I'm using pure Django-url Thanks again

Comment: @Anthony: I want to redirect to my domain from appspot.

Comment: Sorry, this question (and answer) are specific to web2py. I suggest you open a new question if you need to ask about Django.

Answer (score 1):

That goes into your request handler.

Using example from [web2py documentation](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/04#request):

Example 8

> In controller: simple_examples.py

```
def redirectme():
    redirect(URL('hello3'))
```

You'd want to do something like this:

```
def some_function():
    if request.env.http_host.endswith('appspot.com'):
        redirect(URL('www.yourdomain.com'))
```

Comment: Note, in `URL('www.yourdomain.com')`, web2py will interpret 'www.yourdomain.com' as the controller and will produce a URL like '/yourapp/www.yourdomain.com'. Instead, you need `URL(host='www.yourdomain.com')`. Also, it's better to put this in a model (outside a function). See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8681704/440323.

Answer (score 0):

With webapp2 here is something like what I did, where BaseHandler is the type of all my handlers:

```
class BaseHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, request, response):
        self.initialize(request, response)
        if request.host.endswith('appspot.com'):
            query_string = self.request.query_string
            redirect_to = 'https://www.example.com' + self.request.path + ("?" + query_string if query_string else "")
            self.redirect(redirect_to, permanent=True, abort=True)
```